# Why is the body and animated background separated (not on top of eachother) on my HTML-website?

Tags: html, css

I'm a student learning HTML and CSS. For a school project we need to make a simple game and I'm currently working on the design of the game lobby.

I wanted to add a moving smoke/fog overlay on top of my background but behind my tables, buttons and everything so I searched for some tutorials and was able to implement this. The only problem I have is that the background with the smoke is underneath the rest of my code. I tried searching for the problem myself but wasn't able to find it.

Here are the fog images
[image: fog1]

[image: fog2]

Here is a picture: [image: picture]

It would be amazing if someone could help me find the problem and how to fix this issue!

**Here is the DEMO**

```css
@font-face{
    src: url("images/font.otf");
    font-family: lobbyfont;
}
.quick_game_button{
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 240px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url("images/dirtyclothes3.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.quick_game_text{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.quick_game_text:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.lobby_title{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 7%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
article.background_music{
    background: rgba(43,45,47,.7);
    border: solid black 2px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
}
p.music_text{
    font-family: "lobbyfont", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-left: 4px;
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#sound_button{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 3;
}
.online_players_table{
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: -215px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 380px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: 3;
}
.friends_table{
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-left: 70%;
    margin-top: -421px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 384px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: 3;
}
.caption_titel{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.caption_friends{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.70);
    color: dimgrey;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(43,45,47,0.70);
}
.add_friend_text{
    margin: 3px;
    width: 40px;
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    background: rgb(43, 45, 47);
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.add_friend_text:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.invite_friend_text{
    margin: 3px;
    width: 58px;
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    background: rgb(43, 45, 47);
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.invite_friend_text:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
th{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.absolute-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("images/1989118_auto_x2.jpg");
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fog {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fog-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fog-img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300vw;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fog-img-first {
    background: url("images/fog-1.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fog-img-second {
    background: url("images/fog-2.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
    z-index: 2;
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-200vw, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--lobby title-->
    <p class="lobby_title">LOBBY</p>

<!--quick game button-->
    <section class="quick_game_button">
        <p class="quick_game_text" id="quick_game_Button">Quick Game</p>
    </section>

<!--online players table-->
    <table class="online_players_table">
        <caption class="caption_titel">Online Players</caption>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%">player 2</th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%">player 5</th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%">player 8</th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%">player 11</th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="add_friend_text">add</p></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

<!--friends table-->
    <table class="friends_table">
        <caption class="caption_friends">Friends</caption>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%">friend2</th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%">friend 5</th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%">friend 8</th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%">friend 11</th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 75%"></th>
            <th><p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

<!--background music script-->
    <article>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function playpause() {
                let snd = document.getElementById("sound");
                let snd_btn = document.getElementById("sound_button");
                snd.muted = !snd.muted; if(snd.muted){ snd_btn.innerHTML = "<img alt='Pause The Music' title='Music Paused' src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/30_Sound_off-24.png' />"; } else{ snd_btn.innerHTML = "<img alt='Play The Music' title='Music Playing' src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/29_Sound_alt-24.png' />"; } }
        </script>
        <audio autoplay loop id="sound" src="music/[HQ 1080p]Call of Duty Black Ops Multiplayer Menu Music + Download Link (mp3cut.net).mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    </article>
    <article class="background_music">
        <p class="music_text">MUSIC</p><div id='sound_button' onClick="playpause()"><img title='Music Playing' alt='Play The Music' src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/29_Sound_alt-24.png'/></div>
    </article>

<!--fog background-->
   <section class="fog">
        <div class="absolute-bg"></div>
        <div class="fog-container">
            <div class="fog-img fog-img-first"></div>
            <div class="fog-img fog-img-second"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you have the image of "fog" you try to implement as background ? because we would need that to help you

Comment: @MaxiGui Yes, I just added the images

Comment: Hey, you have to make a separate container where you can put your top background `fog` and `tables` and now you want to set the position `relative` of that container and then you want to set the position `absolute` of the `fog` background and this will work.

Comment: That way you can set the `fogs` behind your `tables` and remember to set the `z-index` of both of your `fogs` container and `tables` container

Comment: set a high `z-index` for you `table` container and a low for your `fogs` container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: novice here so take this with a pinch of salt.
I've provided a solution below that certainly isn't the most elegant but will help you on your way without altering too much of your code.

- We can take the section of class 'fog' out entirely for the time being to simplify things a little.
- We then take the div of class 'absolute-bg' and place this immediately below the body, making sure that all of your remaining elements are within this div and therefore (visually) 'on top' of your background.
- We then set the 'absolute-bg' class to have a lower z-index than everything else (e.g. -1).
- Next, we can take the div of 'fog-container' and give it two simple CSS properties: position: fixed; top: 0;
- This removes the element from the Document flow and places it in a fixed position relative to the browser window, in this case, top: 0.
- Finally, you want to be able to click-through your div 'fog-container' which now sits 'on-top' of everything else when rendered, therefore, we can add these two properties to .fog-container: pointer-events: none; touch-action: none;

Hope this helps. Elegant, no? A push in the right direction? Hopefully!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Your fog section is still here but I've commented it out -->
  <!-- <section class="fog"></section> -->
  <div class="absolute-bg">

    <!--lobby title-->
    <p class="lobby_title">LOBBY</p>

    <!--quick game button-->
    <section class="quick_game_button">
      <p class="quick_game_text" id="quick_game_Button">Quick Game</p>
    </section>

    <!--online players table-->
    <table class="online_players_table">
      <caption class="caption_titel">Online Players</caption>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">player 2</th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">player 5</th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">player 8</th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">player 11</th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="add_friend_text">add</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--friends table-->
    <table class="friends_table">
      <caption class="caption_friends">Friends</caption>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">friend2</th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">friend 5</th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">friend 8</th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%">friend 11</th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 75%"></th>
        <th>
          <p class="invite_friend_text">invite</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--background music script-->
    <article>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function playpause() {
          let snd = document.getElementById("sound");
          let snd_btn = document.getElementById("sound_button");
          snd.muted = !snd.muted;
          if (snd.muted) {
            snd_btn.innerHTML = "<img alt='Pause The Music' title='Music Paused' src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/30_Sound_off-24.png' />";
          } else {
            snd_btn.innerHTML = "<img alt='Play The Music' title='Music Playing' src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/29_Sound_alt-24.png' />";
          }
        }
      </script>
      <audio autoplay loop id="sound" src="music/[HQ 1080p]Call of Duty Black Ops Multiplayer Menu Music + Download Link (mp3cut.net).mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    </article>
    <article class="background_music">
      <p class="music_text">MUSIC</p>
      <div id='sound_button' onClick="playpause()"><img title='Music Playing' alt='Play The Music' src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/29_Sound_alt-24.png' /></div>
    </article>

    <!--fog background-->

    <div class="fog-container">
      <div class="fog-img fog-img-first"></div>
      <div class="fog-img fog-img-second"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
@font-face{
    src: url("images/font.otf");
    font-family: lobbyfont;
}
.quick_game_button{
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 240px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url("images/dirtyclothes3.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.quick_game_text{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.quick_game_text:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.lobby_title{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 7%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
article.background_music{
    background: rgba(43,45,47,.7);
    border: solid black 2px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
}
p.music_text{
    font-family: "lobbyfont", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-left: 4px;
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#sound_button{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 3;
}
.online_players_table{
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: -215px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 380px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: 3;
}
.friends_table{
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-left: 70%;
    margin-top: -421px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 384px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: 3;
}
.caption_titel{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.caption_friends{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.70);
    color: dimgrey;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(43,45,47,0.70);
}
.add_friend_text{
    margin: 3px;
    width: 40px;
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    background: rgb(43, 45, 47);
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.add_friend_text:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.invite_friend_text{
    margin: 3px;
    width: 58px;
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    background: rgb(43, 45, 47);
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.invite_friend_text:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
th{
    font-family: lobbyfont, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.absolute-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("images/1989118_auto_x2.jpg");
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* not using this for now */

/* .fog {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2; */
    
.fog-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
.fog-img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300vw;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fog-img-first {
    background: url("images/fog-1.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
            animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fog-img-second {
    background: url("images/fog-2.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
            animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
    z-index: 2;
}
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-200vw, 0, 0);
    }
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-200vw, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that looks really good, u helped me out so much thanks!! Also, what do u mean when u say the code isn't elegant?

Comment: I should have clarified what I meant by elegant! I simply mean that a senior dev with in-depth knowledge of HTML would likely have written a cleaner solution to the same problem using less code. As long as my solution helps you, that's great!